# Make dotted background for textarea

Tags: css

I have problems with creating such background.

[image]

I`ve tried radial gradient but it doesn`t look very good.
The latest thing i have done is a dashed backdround with help of linear gradient. But even it have some problems with background.

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(128,128,128,1) 1%, rgba(128,128,128,0) 5%, rgba(128,128,128,0) 10%);
```

Thanks everyone who participate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an SVG as background. You should have a better rendring than a radial-gradient:

```css
textarea {
  line-height:1.5em;
  font-size:18pw;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 6 6"><circle cx="3" cy="3" r="2" fill="red" /></svg>') 
     0 1em/8px 1.5em 
     yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
some content here
also here
</textarea>
```

For a dashed one consider a repeating-gradient:

```css
textarea {
  line-height:1.5em;
  font-size:18pw;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:
     repeating-linear-gradient(to right , transparent 0 5px,yellow 0 8px),
     repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 calc(1.5em - 2px),#000 0 1.5em)
     yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
some content here
also here
</textarea>
```