# How to add border-bottom with full width for all line-break using css?

Tags: html, css

I have small css code working on border-bottom. It work for single line text or only last line for multiple lines break.

Css:

```
.underline{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: block; //can not use inline because of fullwidth problem.
}
```

Html:

```
  <div class="underline">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry ....
  </div>
```

[image]

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64404123/8620333 (check the last snippet)

Comment: Dear Temani Afif, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap text with `span` tag.

```css
.underline{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.underline span {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
  <div class="underline">
    <span>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: you don't need `box-decoration-break: clone;` since you are not applying any padding or start/end styles

Comment: you also don't need the -webkit- version

Answer (score -1):

```css
.underline {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

You can use `text-decoration` property.

Comment: Dear inongun, thanks but it's not fullwidth underline.

Comment: Not only does that not use border-bottom, but the dotted underline makes the text look like a recaptcha test.